# eliminate boot time of cloud instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud

I am working on an automated project that requires high computing power at irregular intervals.

My original ideas to solve this problem in economically efficient way was to create a couple of `google cloud compute` instances and boot them any time a need to perform computation and then stop them when it's done.

My problem is that `booting` an instance `takes almost a minute`, and then `another minute` to `start` my process. `Calculation` often takes just `60s`.

I am wasting 2/3 of the total calculation time booting the instance and starting the process. Than it also takes 1 min to shutdown an instance. That time also needs to be paid. In this scenario only 1/4 of costs are used on computation.

Has anyone had a similar problem? What approach did you take eliminate this time (and money) wasting? It would be great if I could put an instance to "sleep" (and not be charged for sleep time) and later resume it with minimal delay.

Comment: Rather than booting your own instances to run your short lived computational code, deploy your code as a lambda function or use the similar Google functions.

Comment: I don't own the source code, but merely the executable.

Comment: Do you have not enough work to keep even the smallest instance running 24x7?

Comment: Hi sanjihan, if the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault's way to say thank you for the time and effort someone took to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you can create a Docker container from your application and if you're not bound to GCP and can use AWS instead you can then run your container on **[AWS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/)** - it's a serverless platform for running Docker containers.

With **AWS Fargate** you only pay for the time your container runs (with a tiny overhead for downloading it from the repository, but that's only a second or two), and you don't need to start up / shut down any underlying infrastructure. [Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/pricing/) is per second with a 1-minute minimum and price per minute depends on your selected *CPU* and *RAM* configuration.

Alternatively you can run your binary in **AWS Lambda** - it supports not only running source code but any Linux executable. See [Running Arbitrary Executables in AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/).

**Update:** As you mentioned in the comments your workload runs on Windows and needs a lot of CPUs - in that case you may still need to run it on a standard AWS EC2 Windows instance. Have a look at **[AWS Spot Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/)** for a way to save up to 90% of the runtime costs.

GCP may have some similar services, not sure.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks man! I'm already catching up on Docker and Fargate. One thing I didn't explicitly say in question, because I am also interested in general solution, is that my executable only works on windows machines. You can think of my workload in this way: start Excel and run excel script that does some things with an excel file located on the same machine and reports solution to the master (it's not really excel, but is good for explanation purposes)

Comment: Docker containers seem to be the perfect solution for my problem. Unfortunately I haven't found a service that offers more than 4vCPU per container and has per minute/second billing. I'd really need 16 or at least 8 vCPUs. Are you aware of any such service?

Comment: @sanjihan what are you *really* doing? What software *exactly* are you using? Perhaps the processing can be run in parallel in a couple of smaller containers? If you really need Windows with 16 CPUs then no, Fargate is not an option. You'll have to run it on a standard EC2 instance. Look at AWS Spot Instances (https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/) for a way to save money.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you may use a [stop/start](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance#stop_an_instance) approach to your instance. This will cut down on booting time. Moreover, you do not incur charges when your instances are stopped, however keep in mind that other resources attached to your instances will be billed. For example, persistent disks and external IP addresses.

Now in regards to @MLu response for Docker container, [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) only supports Container-Optomized OS (cos) and Ubuntu, so Windows OS is not supported on GKE. In that line of thought, you might need to have a look at Azure if you want to go the container route.

Google cloud functions is the simplest way to run your code in the cloud but you do need to own the code.